# How to test exception from imported function using Python pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I test exception from imported function by using pytest ?
For example,
in main file.py I have :

```py
def function():
  if 3 != 3:
    raise Exception("Error")
```

in testfile.py I have :

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '..//main/')
import file

def test_exception():
    file.function()
   # need to test exception here
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? Did you try putting `pytest test exception raised` into a search engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pytest.raises` like so:

```py
def test_exception():
    with pytest.raises(SomeExceptionClass) as e:
        file.function()
    assert "Some informative error message" in str(e.value)
```

Where `SomeExceptionClass` would be the specific error you expect to occur. This will raise an assertion error if the function does not raise an error (or if it raises a different error type).

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way:

```
import sys
import os

def function():
  raise Exception("Error")




def test_exception():
  try:
    function()
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)

test_exception()
```